# asp.net reload page after export to excel

Tags: asp.net, export-to-excel

I have a page which exports a document to excel on button click. What I need to do is refresh the page after the excel document has been sent.

I am trying to register a script which will cause a page refresh but cant get it to register at the same time as exporting to excel.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, Page.GetType(), "test", "alert('Done');", True)

Response.Clear()
Response.ClearHeaders()
Response.AddHeader("Refresh", "3; url=" + Request.RawUrl)
Response.ContentType = strMimeType
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=CompleteReport." + strFilenameExtension)
Response.BinaryWrite(bytFileContent)
Response.End()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make

#### only one response for each requests

(first excel export, and the second would be the refresh).
After first response.end, you can't do anything.
You have to solve the excel export another way, with component etc. 
And after export you can call

```
Response.redirect("your page");
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically this can not be done if you want it reloaded only *after* the file has downloaded as it it not possible to find out when that is. Also you are clearing the response out and then writing the excel so the script isn't even returned from the server. The refresh-header is not being used by the browser when downloading a file either.

What you can do is to use the aspx-page to include a script like:

```
function onclick() {
  window.location.href = 'loadmyfile.ashx?parameters...';

  refreshPage();
}
```

The above will however refresh the page immediately on click so that might not be what you are after.